# PHP - Doctrine setting null to variables

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

This is my first time working with OO PHP, MVC and Doctrine, so I'm probably doing something really wrong!!
I'm trying to save an object into the database using Doctrine, the problem is that the object is completaly null

this is the error that PHP returns me:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'NM_TIPO_SUPLEMENTO' cannot be null' in C:\Users\Alexandre\apache\workspace\projetoPeso\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php:138 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Alexandre\apache\workspace\projetoPeso\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php(138): PDOStatement->execute(NULL) #1 C:\Users\Alexandre\apache\workspace\projetoPeso\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php(278): Doctrine\DBAL\Statement->execute() #2 C:\Users\Alexandre\apache\workspace\projetoPeso\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php(929): Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister->executeInserts() #3 C:\Users\Alexandre\apache\workspace\projetoPeso\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php(318): Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->executeInserts(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)) #4 C:\Users\Alexandre\apache\workspace\projetoPeso\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\E in C:\Users\Alexandre\apache\workspace\projetoPeso\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException.php on line 47
```

I know that I did the mapping correctly, because if I change the name of the column on my model it says my column doesn't exists

this is my model:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="tb_tipo_suplemento")
 **/
class TipoSuplemento {

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer", name="ID_TIPO_SUPLEMENTO") @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY") **/
    protected $idTipo;
    /** @Column(type="string", name="NM_TIPO_SUPLEMENTO", nullable=false) **/
    protected $nmTipo;

    public function setIdTipo($idTipo) {
        $this->idTipo = $idTipo;
    }
    public function getIdTipo() {
        return $this->idTipo;
    }

    public function setNmTipo($NmTipo) {
        $this->NmTipo = $NmTipo;
    }
    public function getNmTipo() {
        return $this->NmTipo;
    }
}

?>
```

my controller:

```
<?php
class ctrlTipoSuplemento {
    public function salvarTipoSuplemento() {
        require("../model/TipoSuplemento.php");
        require_once "../bootstrap.php";
        //criar um objeto novo e o preencher
        $tpSuplemento = new TipoSuplemento();
        $tpSuplemento->setNmTipo($_POST['nmTipoSuplemento']);

        $entityManager->persist($tpSuplemento);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }
}
?>
```

my view.php

```
<?php
require("../util/header.php");
require("../util/footer.php");
require("../controller/ctrlTipoSuplemento.php");
getHeader("Manter Tipo de Suplemento", "Tipo de Suplemento");
montarFormulario();
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nmTipoSuplemento" required="required" placeholder="Tipo do Suplemento"><br>
    <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>

<?php

/*
 * Salvar os dados do formulário acima
 */
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $ctrl = new ctrlTipoSuplemento();
    $ctrl->salvarTipoSuplemento();
}
terminarFomulario();
?>

<?php getFooter();?>
```

and bootstrap.php

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/model"), $isDevMode);

// database configuration parameters
$conn = array(
        'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
        'user'     => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'dbname'   => 'suplementos',
);

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_tipo_suplemento` (
  `ID_TIPO_SUPLEMENTO` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NM_TIPO_SUPLEMENTO` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_TIPO_SUPLEMENTO`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thank you so much!

**EDIT 1:** Added view.php
**EDIT 2:** Is there something wrong with getters and setters? If I replace `private` by `public`, and set the variable value like this `$tpSuplemento->nmTipo = $_POST['nmTipoSuplemento'];` it works

Comment: Am I missing something or is your `$_POST['nmTipoSuplemento']` just `null`? You defined the column as not nullable. The errors says you're trying to insert a `null` value into that column. Can you check the contents of the `$_POST` variable?

Comment: it's not null, there's a HTML form that sets value to it, if I `echo` its value, it shows what I typed in the form, so I'm pretty sure that the `$_POST['nmTipoSuplemento']` is not null, I added the view.php to the question

Comment: Can you get the actual SQL query that your doctrine query generates? You can either get it from the doctrine object or from your sql log.

Comment: From Doctrine: `INSERT INTO tb_tipo_suplemento (NM_TIPO_SUPLEMENTO) VALUES (?)`

Comment: The key part is not there yet. What value is bound to the `?`? It for sure will be in the SQL log, but you should be able to find it by stepping through the code too.

Comment: from MySQL Log: `START TRANSACTION INSERT INTO tb_tipo_suplemento (NM_TIPO_SUPLEMENTO) VALUES (NULL) ROLLBACK` The value just went null somehow

Comment: There is the problem, you are either doing something wrong when you bind that value, or the value you bind is `NULL`.

Comment: I guess it's something wrong with the get/set, if I replace `private`  `public` and set the value like this `$tpSuplemento->nmTipo = $_POST['nmTipoSuplemento'];` it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I see is that your column `NM_TIPO_SUPLEMENTO` does not allow null values. Did you want you column to allow nulls or not?

Here you have `nullable=false`:

```
/** @Column(type="string", name="NM_TIPO_SUPLEMENTO", nullable=false) **/
protected $nmTipo;
```

If you did not want to allow nulls, make sure you are not passing in a null value into your entity for $nmTipo.

If you did want to allow nulls, then change `nullable=false` to `nullable=true`. Additionally you need to make your database table for NM_TIPO_SUPLEMENTO is set to allow `nulls`.

---

The reason setting your getter/setter method to `public` works is because you cannot use a `private` method externally. A private method can only be used internally by your class. I'm not sure why you didn't get a syntax error for doing that.

---

Another issue is in your getter/setters. You have typed it wrong. It should look like this:

```
public function setNmTipo($NmTipo) {
    $this->nmTipo = $NmTipo;
}
public function getNmTipo() {
    return $this->nmTipo;
}
```

Note the lowercase `$this->nmTipo`. That is not the same as `$this->NmTipo`

Comment: I did want it to not be nullable.. The problem was really the uppercase N, thank you so much, it's working now!!!